# Using node.js watch with OWFS

Tags: node.js

I tried to use node.js Watch on a onewire temperature device in OWFS but no evets are fired when temperature change.

(running on Raspberry pi).

Someting like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var fo = '/mnt/1wire/10.8782E4000800/temperature';
fs.watchFile(fo, function (curr, prev) {
    var temp = fs.readFileSync(fo);
    console.log('the temperarture is: ' + temp);
});
```

i suspect that OWFS is not a 'real' file system and that is the reason (file timestamp is not updated on temperature update).

Is there a way to get arround this?

Comment: Yes, I just verified that nothing about the owfs filesystem dates/times changes (even with obscure ls options) when temperatures are updated. I get around that by using Node-RED and a timed "injector" node. They can read the 1-wire files at your choice of interval and do most anything you want with the info. But sometimes it appears the files are not updated for half an hour or more... Node-RED faithfully logs what's in the files, but it isn't changing. And then it makes a step change... So I'm searching for a way to know if owfs is rewriting the same value to the files, or just not updating t

Comment: I think it would be much better to poll the file rather than try to watch. Imagine the minute fluctuations in temperature triggering this code if the time stamps were indeed updating!

Comment: A slightly different approach, but I wrote a Node-RED node type that talks to owserver directly: http://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-owfs